# delete vector entries based on another vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors

```
a <- c(1:20)
b <- c(2,11,14)
```

I want to delete the entries in the a vector based on the vector entries in b (I want the 2nd, 11th, and 14th entries deleted).

I've tried several methods, including:

```
c <- a[!a %in% b]
```

but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions? I've tried searching SO, but can only find deleting based on values.

Comment: How about `a[-b]`? Does that do what you want?

Comment: I'm relatively new to R, so I don't quite know the nuances yet. Also, the solution will be applied across a vector with a length of 3.1 million because I'm processing a raw text file.

Comment: You can try it out...don't know what better way exists to do this other than what I provided above.

Comment: Thanks @Gopala, that did it. I was overthinking the solution. If you post as a solution, I'll up vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply index into `a` and remove the elements at indices in `b` as follows:

```
a <- c(1:20)
b <- c(2,11,14)
a[-b]
 [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

I created 3.1 million entries and am randomly sampling 100,000 to remove. As can be seen, it is blazing fast.

```
a <- 1:3100000
b <- sample(a, 100000)
system.time(a[-b])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.024   0.003   0.027
```

Edited: Adding this extra check option based on comment below by akrun and thelatemail to handle the case where `b` might be null.

```
a[if(length(b)) -b else TRUE]
```

Answer (score 3):

The approach by @Gopala works in most cases except when the 'b' vector is NULL. To make it a bit more general, we can get the logical condition using `seq_along(a)` with `%in%`

```
a[!seq_along(a) %in% b]
#[1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Now, if we change 'b' to

```
b <- vector('integer')
a[-b]
#integer(0)
a[!seq_along(a) %in% b]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

The former returns a vector of length 0, while the `%in%` approach returns the whole vector 'a'.

Other method is obviously more efficient, but in case if we need an approach that works on the case I mentioned, this can be used.

```
system.time(a[-b])
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.07    0.00    0.08 
system.time(a[!seq_along(a) %in% b])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.17    0.01    0.18
```

The approach posted by @thelatemail to make the first approach general

```
system.time(a[if(length(b)==0) TRUE else -b])
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.05    0.00    0.05
```

NOTE: Benchmark data from @Gopala's post.

Comment: Or just check if it's empty `a[if(length(b)==0) TRUE else -b]`